# How does the MATLAB A\B compute, when A is singular square and full (dense) matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I am working on linear equations like `A*X = B`. I got a matrix like `A = magic(4)` and `B = [1;3;2;4]`. I used several methods to solve this problem, also including MATLAB `A\B`.

What's annoyed is the resulf of MATLAB `A\B` is different from those of NumPy, SciPy and LAPACK (`LAPACKE_dgetrf`, `LAPACKE_dgels`, `LAPACKE_dgelsd`).

The folowing are the results.

MATLAB `A\B` (Ubuntu Matlab 2021a and Matlab Online)

```matlab
>> A = magic(4)


A =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

>> B = [1;3;2;4]

B =

     1
     3
     2
     4

>> A \ B
RCOND =  4.625929e-18。  

ans =

   -0.0098
    0.0735
    0.1985
    0.0319
>> lsqr(A, B)

ans =

    0.0110
    0.1360
    0.1360
    0.0110

>> x = pinv(A)*B

x =

    0.0110
    0.1360
    0.1360
    0.0110

>> [L, U, P] = lu(A) %lu decomposition

L =

    1.0000         0         0         0
    0.2500    1.0000         0         0
    0.5625    0.4352    1.0000         0
    0.3125    0.7685    1.0000    1.0000


U =

   16.0000    2.0000    3.0000   13.0000
         0   13.5000   14.2500   -2.2500
         0         0   -1.8889    5.6667
         0         0         0    0.0000


P =

     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0
>> y = L \ (P * B) % LU tril solver

y =

    1.0000
    3.7500
   -0.1944
    0.0000

>> x = U \ y % LU triu solver

x =

   -0.0098
    0.0735
    0.1985
    0.0319
```

Python `numpy.linalg.solve(a, b)`

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[16., 2., 3., 13.], [5., 11., 10., 8.], [9., 7., 6., 12.], [4., 14., 15., 1.]]);
b = np.array([[1.],[3.],[2.],[4]]);
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
'''
x = 
array([[ 0.10799632],
       [ 0.42693015],
       [-0.15487132],
       [-0.0859375 ]])
'''
```

Python `scipy.linalg.solve(a, b)`

```py
from scipy import linalg

x1 = linalg.solve(a, b)
'''
x1 = 
array([[ 0.10799632],
       [ 0.42693015],
       [-0.15487132],
       [-0.0859375 ]])
'''
```

Octave Online

```matlab
octave:1> A = magic(4)
A =

   16    2    3   13
    5   11   10    8
    9    7    6   12
    4   14   15    1

octave:2> B = [1;3;2;4]
B =

   1
   3
   2
   4

octave:3> A\B
warning: matrix singular to machine precision, rcond = 1.30614e-17
ans =

   0.011029
   0.136029
   0.136029
   0.011029
```

Lapack `LAPACKE_degelsd`

```bash
a = 
  Matrix(Row = 4, Col = 4, Major = ColMajor)
            16             2             3            13
             5            11            10             8
             9             7             6            12
             4            14            15             1

B = 
  Vector(Size = 4)
             1
             3
             2
             4

info = 0
X = 
  Vector(Size = 4)
      0.107996
       0.42693
     -0.154871
    -0.0859375
```

My problem is what the MATLAB `A \ B` exactly computes. I know that `pinv(A) * B` computes the minimum norm least-squares solution, and so do `np.linalg.solve` and `scipy.linalg.solve`.

And the MATLAB reference page said:

- If `A` is a square matrix, then `A\B` is roughly equal to `inv(A)*B`, but MATLAB processes `A\B` differently and more robustly.
- If the rank of `A` is less than the number of columns in `A`, then `x = A\B` is not necessarily the minimum norm solution. You can compute the minimum norm least-squares solution using `x = lsqminnorm(A,B)` or `x = pinv(A)*B`.

Well I know the solution is not unique when A is nearly singular.  There are many feasible solutions (like numpy, octave and LAPACK. They solve this problem to minimize the norm of `||AX - B||` by `QR`, `SVD(pinv)`). However what makes matlab get its solution, and what's the magic?

So, I want to ask what the operation `A\B` exactly computes and what the result of `A\B` is when `A` is a singular square matrix.

P.S.

I do know there isn't an unique solution for linear equations when its coefficient matrix is singular or nearly singular .aka. ill conditioned. According to the reference page of `\`(mldivide), `x = A\B` is not necessarily the minimum norm solution. I want to know the underlying details of `A\B`. If it is not necessarily the minimum norm solution, then what? As I know, scipy, numpy, LAPACK and Octave get a minimum norm solution. Is there another fomulation for this problem that I haven't know?

Comment: The documentation has a really good diagram explaning which algorithm it uses in any situation. Is there something from that you did not understand or that is not helpful to you? https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html .

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `numpy.linalg.solve` and `scipy.linalg.solve` are the same function. Your reciprocal condition number is approximately zero, which means that there is no unique solution to the system of equations. Your solution is basically noise. A different algorithm will produce a different set of random values.

Comment: Actually, my version of MATLAB (R2022a on macOS) gives the same result as NumPy. Go figure!

Comment: It is probably more about figuring how to reduce your system to a well conditioned one, isn't it?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks, I do refer this page for the internal techs of `A\B`. Also I have implemented my mldivide by LAPACK. In my case, A = magic(4) matches the case where A is square and chol(A) failed. So mldivide uses the LU solver.

Comment: @AnderBiguri So mldivide uses the LU solver. However I cannot figure out how to deal with U(4,4) = 0.(refer the main body of this question post)

Comment: @CrisLuengo exlpained exactly what happens/

Comment: Are you sure this is actually what you want to do? Can you add a bit more information about how you get such a singular system? In general, you get singular matrices when the problem is poorly formulated

Comment: @BillBokeey I am writing a linalg solver, so I have to handle singular and nearly singular matrix. Matlab `A\B` gives a satisfied result, however it's not necessary the minimum norm solution as its reference page said. So I want to know the detail of its solution. I tired several methods, and none of them gets the same results as Matlab `A\B`. So I get more curious. Aren't there others curious about this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to try to see this problem, but the one I would recommend is that it makes no sense to try to solve `Ax = B`, when `A` is ill-conditioned:

Look at the 1D case for example. What is `x` when `0.x = b`?

We know that this problem has infinitely many solutions if `b = 0` or none if `b~=0`. What does MATLAB say about that:

```
0\0

ans =

   NaN


0\1

ans =

   Inf
```

Not very convincing. What about `lsqminnorm`:

```
lsqminnorm(0,0)

ans =

     0

lsqminnorm(0,1)

ans =

     0
```

See? `lsqminnorm` gives you a valid answer only when there are infinitely many solutions. When there are none, it just tries to minimize `|| 0.x - b ||`. Does this make sense? Are you satisfied with it returning `x = 0` as a solution of `0.x = 1`?

Back to your problem. Let's try a different value for `B`:

```
B2 = [1;1;2;1];

out2 = A\B2;

A*out2

out_minnorm = lsqminnorm(A,B2);

A*out_minnorm

out_pinv = pinv(A)*B2;

A*out_pinv

ans =

         0
   -1.0000
         0
   -2.6250


ans =

    1.1500
    1.4500
    1.5500
    0.8500


ans =

    1.1500
    1.4500
    1.5500
    0.8500
```

Are any of these values for `x` acceptable? Even though the last two results are the minimum norm solutions, these don't really mean much.

So, my take on your problem is to check if [`rcond`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rcond.html) gets close to machine precision, because not returning any result is in my opinion better than returning something that doesn't make sense:

```
if rcond(A) < 1e-12

    error('A is singular, the problem seems to be ill-conditioned');

else

    out = B\A;

end
```